# Why hibernate session save update row instead of insert row?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, maven, java-ee-7

I have installed Postgres version 10.1 on windows7x64. I have got a database "postgres" with one table "dbuser" and columns "user_id" and "username". I am using Intelij and Maven. I am using Session from hibernate to try to insert a row into a table.

App.java

```
package com.hibernateTest;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    dbuser dbuser = new dbuser();
    dbuser.setUser_id(556);
    dbuser.setUsername("waaagr");       
    session.save(dbuser);
    //session.merge(dbuser);//my mistake---old code
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package com.hibernateTest;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

dbuser.java:

```
    package com.hibernateTest;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "dbuser")
public class dbuser implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long user_id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;


    public dbuser() {
    }

    public dbuser(long user_id, String username) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb</property>
        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.hibernateTest.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>HibernateExample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1203-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The problem is that when I run my application I got:

```
Hibernate: select dbuser0_.user_id as user1_0_0_, dbuser0_.username as username0_0_ from dbuser dbuser0_ where dbuser0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: insert into dbuser (username, user_id) values (?, ?)
```

The first thing which is strange is that there is values with (?, ?) in the Terminal. And data in the table in the database is only update, but I would like to insert a new row not update a row?
I don't why this code update a row instead of insert a new one, a new row?
Thank you very much.

Comment: The log you provided (in a poorly readable form) seems to specify an `INSERT` statement, not an `UPDATE`. So why do you claim otherwise? The `?` are placeholders for values.

Comment: "Save" is a synonym for INSERT.

Comment: @Kayman "The log you provided (in a poorly readable form)" -> corrected (thanks). duffymo Yes I know it that's why I am asking about it why when make select on this table I see that row is update instead of new one.

Comment: `dbuser.setUser_id(556);` This will make hibernate to update the row with key 556. If you wan't to insert a new row, then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbuser dbuser = new dbuser();
dbuser.setUser_id(556);
dbuser.setUsername("waaagr");       
session.merge(dbuser);
```

So what you are doing here, is telling the hibernate that some user with id=556 probably exists in the database, and you want to merge your changes into the DB. This is so called **detached** entity.

What merge is doing, is fetching given entity by provided id (thus `SELECT`), check if there are some differences between data in database and in your object, and commits `UPDATE` operation on "dirty fields". In the same time, merge will return **managed** entity. This is how `merge` according to JPA specification works in general.

In your case, you have lied to hibernate that such entity already exists, but Hibernate know about this (becouse of empty results set for ID fetch) and it performs `INSERT` insteed of `UPDATE`.

So to wrap it up: By providing ID you are indicating that given entity should alredy exist in the database and merge is possible. If you would like to create new user (even with given id) use `save` insteed of `merge`

Comment: Thank you very much it is my fault that I have attached a code with merge. I tried to use "save" instead of "merge", but the results are the same and I don't know why? Maybe I have got some bug in configurations.

Comment: The code is quite the same. Instead of "session.merge(dbuser);" I have got "session.save(dbuser);".

Comment: remove id from the entity and it will be save as new without select.

Comment: When I removed id I have got a communicat in Terminal "No identifier specified for entity: com.hibernateTest.dbuser"

Comment: @user2856064 use `persist` isteed of `save` - without ID ofc.

Comment: Having autoincrement in the db - not possible. uncomment that  //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)